# How to probe a specific value using cout in a map of map in C++

Tags: c++

```
map<string, map<int, set<int> > >myMap

set<int>valSet;
valSet.insert(1);valSet.insert(2);valSet.insert(3);

myMap ["Name"] [5] = valSet;
```

When I do:

```
cout<<myMap ["Name"] [5] ;
```

It is not diplaying `{1,2,3}`

Please help regarding this

Edit:
      I understood the point that set cannot be displayed using <<
      operator. I would like to revisit my question. I am creating a map of map 
      data structure. After creating map, I would like to probe the individual 
      contents instead of iterating all the contents. Please find the code given 
      below:

---

```
#include <map>  
#include <iostream>  
#include <string>
#include <set>

using namespace std;
int main() 
{
//Defining Map structure
map<string, map<int, set<int> > >myMap;

set<int>valSet,valSet1,valSet2,valSet3;
valSet.insert(1);valSet.insert(2);valSet.insert(3);
valSet1.insert(4);valSet1.insert(5);valSet1.insert(6);
valSet2.insert(7);valSet2.insert(8);valSet2.insert(9);    
valSet3.insert(10);valSet3.insert(11);valSet3.insert(12);

myMap ["Name-1"] [1] = valSet;    //Creating map
myMap ["Name-1"] [2] = valSet1;
myMap ["Name-2"] [3] = valSet2;
myMap ["Name-3"] [4] = valSet3;

  }


Note:
1) I am aware of iterating the entire **myMap** values.

My Question:
1) How to display the contents in  **myMap ["Name-1"] [2]** alone. 

2) Is it possible to iterate to find the contents in specific key


Edit2: I finally found the answer 

To get the values mapped in myMap ["Name-1"] [2] can be retrieved in the 
following way:



set<int> some = myMap ["Name-1"] [2];

for (auto it: some)
{
cout<<"Values in myMap ["Name-1"] [2] :"<<it<<","; \\ Outputs- 4,5,6
}
```

Comment: Simple. `std::set<Anything>` isn't printable (by default). I assume you are getting a compiler error? (You should include that in your question).

Comment: Instead of "it is not displaying", you should clearly state the problem in the form of a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

[`std::set`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) doesn't have a `operator<<` defined for it.

Either define your own `std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<int>& s)`. Eg. :

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, const std::set<int>& s) {
  os << "{";
  std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, ","));
  os << "}";
  return os;
}
```

Be careful about unintentionally calling this though - you might be hiding mistakes (ref. @Peter's comment below).

Alternatively, you can write a print function (part of a wrapper class around the set or otherwise) of some kind to print the contents of a `std::set` to a `std::ostream` in the format that you want. Eg. :

```
void print_set(std::ostream& os, const std::set<int>& s) {
  os << "{";
  std::copy(s.begin(), s.end(), std::ostream_iterator<int>(os, ","));
  os << "}";
  return os;
}
```

Comment: I'd suggest it is inadvisable to define an `operator<<()` for `std::set<Anything>`.     Trying to print a whole standard container (except in special cases, like `std::string`) is often a programmer mistake.  Having the code build and produce output will, at best, mask such errors.   If you have a standard container than you really want to print using stream operators, wrap it in a class, and provide an `operator<<()` for that class.

Comment: @Peter : I'm not here to judge whether the OP's use case is a mistake. But you do make a good point about unintentionally calling such `operator<<`, and hiding mistakes that way. I'll include a note ref. that in my answer. Thank you.

Comment: My sincere thanks to all of you.. Will work on the stated idea

Comment: @Peter: Can you explain why you think printing a whole standard container is often a programmer mistake? The only times I've ever found myself printing a whole container have been deliberate, usually for debugging purposes or easy serialisation. I concede that it is _possible_ one might have intended to iterate instead but it seems unlikely that such a mistake would go unnoticed for very long.